# PHP failing to connect to GMail via IMAP [Edited!!]

Tags: php, ssl, php5, imap, gmail

I have some php code that I'm trying to use to connect to gmail using imap. Here's the code:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$tmp_username = 'username';
$tmp_password = 'password';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die(imap_last_error());
```

And I get this error output everytime i try to connect:

> Warning: imap_open()
>   [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open
>   stream
>   {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX
>   in /var/www/PHP/EmailScript.php on
>   line 14 Login aborted

I dont understand what could be wrong!! I've heard of people having SSL errors but this doesnt seem to be one of those. Please please please help me!!!!!

Edit: When trying to connect to imap.gmail.com through telnet-ssl i get the following output:

> Trying 74.125.155.109...
>   Connected to gmail-imap.l.google.com.
>   Escape character is '^]'.

And Nothign else happens

Comment: try stackoverflow.com?

Comment: for some reason not able to reach the gmail server using telnet imap.gmail.com 993 through the server machine. Can someone help please?

Comment: you need to specify `-z ssl` when using telnet-ssl otherwise you will get what you got.

Comment: @sybreon ok that worked! i used this command: (telnet-ssl -z ssl imap.gmail.com 993) and it connected successfully to gmail. Now, why can't I do it with my php?!?!?!

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to start up the session....

`openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993`

if I do that I get this...

`* OK Gimap ready for requests from <ip_address> 16if41262875qci.66`

Answer (score 1):

If you telnet directly to 993, it should not work correctly because telnet is not on SSL. Use something like `telnet-ssl` or `stunnel` instead to ensure that you are connecting to 993 over SSL. Once that is done, then try to see if you get the welcome message and then try a few IMAP commands to see if they work.

Comment: Well this is the output I get 
"Trying 74.125.155.109...
Connected to gmail-imap.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'." Nothing else though

Comment: That's a pretty normal output for an initial telnet connection. Chances are it connected.

Comment: If you telnet successfully to gmail, you will receive "* OK Gimap ready for requests from..."

Comment: @Alexander: Your telnet session is not running over SSL. You will not get anything that way.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you can connect to the IMAP server from the machine:

```
telnet imap.gmail.com 993
```

If the connection works than check if SSL is installed with php-imap, using phpinfo() you must see something like this

```
imap
IMAP c-Client Version   2004
SSL Support     enabled
Kerberos Support        enabled
```

Other ideas in a similar thread in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274911/connecting-to-gmail-through-imap-with-php-ssl-context-failed)

Comment: Hmmm, i am not able to connect to imap.gmail.com 993 from the machine, very weird! Why do you think this is? I do have SSL installed with php imap though.

Comment: Check if other machines can connect. I think your firewall is not allowing your machine or your server to connect through port 993.

Comment: Ok, now i am able to connect to it through telnet, however still getting errors!

Comment: Are you sure the other variables are OK? First you use $tmp_username and $tmp_password and with imap_open you use $username and $password. Try to connect without using variables to check if everything is fine and don't forget that username must contain the domain.